# How Do You Run GPU Task on Windows Server 2016 Remotely?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2016, gpu

From my understanding, remotely executing GPU tasks is a little tricky because of the way sessions work on Windows. Session 0 does not have access to GPU drivers, and usually when you remotely execute a task it calls it in Session 0.

In order to workaround this, currently I am using PSEXEC.exe like so:

```
C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe \\%computername% /accepteula -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -h -i 1 powershell ".\run-my-gpu-task.ps1"
```

This uses PsExec from [PsTools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools) to connect to *Session 1* somehow (I think RDP) to run whichever task.

From my experience this does not work alone:

```
.\run-my-gpu-task.ps1"
```

I've got this to work however this seems rather messy and tedious. Is there a better way to do this?

**Q: How do you remotely run GPU tasks on Windows Server machines?**

*Context: I'm using AWS Systems Manager to run powershell scripts in Windows Server machines remotely.*